# Find synonym for a specific word with Wikidata SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to construct a query for https://query.wikidata.org/ that finds synonyms for a given string. I know it will involve finding lemmas of the particular string (the string is "kind" in this example) and the `P5973` synonym property. This returns zero results:

```
select ?lexeme ?lemma ?synonym WHERE {
  ?lexeme wikibase:lemma ?lemma.
  FILTER (?lemma ='kind')
  ?lexeme wdt:P5973 ?synonym .
}
```

I've used the string `kind` in this example. I would like to return synonyms for all meanings of the word kind, so both `empathetic` and `type` would be correct responses.

Comment: those lemmas do have a language tag: `select ?lexeme ?lemma ?synonym WHERE {
  VALUES ?lemma {'kind'@en}
  ?lexeme wikibase:lemma ?lemma.
  OPTIONAL {?lexeme wdt:P5973 ?synonym .}
}` - and I can't see synonyms for your example, at least not for both matching lexemes.

Comment: https://w.wiki/GPY

Comment: @AKSW thanks for introducing the idea of the VALUES block. Is it possible to avoid assuming the input language?
@StanislavKralin, that's super helpful! It produces synonyms for one sense of the word `film`, like `movie`, though I'll want to modify it to include synonyms for other senses like `membrane`

Comment: Add them yourself, then run the query again. https://wikidata.org/wiki/Lexeme:L1271#S2

Comment: Ah, I see; I didn't understand at first how incomplete the data is. Thank you @StanislavKralin -- if you want to write your query up as an official answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about the solution to this question: https://johnskinnerportfolio.com/blog/lexemes.html